# How to insert "<<" text in TextView?

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to insert "<<" in  `android:text = "<<"` but there are raise problem with:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - [I18N] Hardcoded string "<<", should use @string resource
    - The value of attribute "android:text" associated with an element type "Button" must not contain the '<' 
     character.
```

Can you tell me how can I insert `<<` in xml file `TextView` text?

Comment: FYI, if you have ADT 19 in Eclipse and if you type << for the `android:text`,it automatically replaces `<<` with `&lt;&lt;`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try `&lt;&lt;` instead of `<<`. You have to escape those characters because they influence your XML layout.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the less-than XML escape character. See a full list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references):

```
&lt;&lt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a string assignment, as the suggestions says. Create a string in `strings.xml`, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ..
    <string name="chevrons">&lt;&lt;</string>

</resources>
```

Then point the `TextView` to that, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:text="@string/chevrons"
>
</TextView>
```